# Bootstrap file input, file name is invisible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJNCx.png)

After I choose which file I want to upload the filename is there but is not visible. I can copy filename and paste it for example to the notepad.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="Photo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input asp-for="Photo" class="form-control custom-file-input">
            <label class="custom-file-label" data-browse="Browse"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $('.custom-file-input').on('change', function () {
            var fileName = document.getElementById("exampleInputFile").files[0].name;
            $(this).next('.form-control-file').addClass("selected").html(fileName);
        })
    </script>
}
```

I saw similar answers and different code examples but doesn't seem to work

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and the solution was adding `style="width: auto; height: auto;opacity:1; position: relative;"` for me.

So basically change this line;

```
<input asp-for="Photo" class="form-control custom-file-input" type="file">
```

To this;

```
<input asp-for="Photo" style="width: auto; height: auto;opacity:1; position: relative;" class="form-control" type="file">
```

I know this sounds stupid to add styling on an element to make it visible but one of .css files trying to hide this, I think this is about the dropzone gem (lib) of my application and probably something similar causing this issue on your side.

[image: Those lines were the problem.]

Answer (score 0):

Change  `<input  asp-for="Photo" class="form-control custom-file-input">` to 
`<input type="file"  asp-for="Photo" class="form-control custom-file-input">`

Comment: As I check the page source the type="file". Still filename is invisible...I have also enctype="multipart/form-data".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this `JS`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="Photo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input asp-for="Photo" class="form-control custom-file-input" type="file">
            <label class="custom-file-label"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
  var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
  $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
});
</script>
```

And give your `<input type="file" />`

https://jsfiddle.net/ilazycoder/9xuym2kj/1/

Comment: Still the same behaviour, filename is invisible. After moving coursor over form, the tool tip with filename appears. And I'm using two different browsers.

Comment: <label class="custom-file-label"></label>

Comment: <label class="custom-file-label"></label> not working

Comment: not working, but after I add this css code: `.custom-file-label { opacity: 0; }
.custom-file-input { opacity: 1; }` it works but looks not so pretty ...

Comment: May be you don't share your full code. It's easy matter. Run jsfiddle.

Comment: @Mac Is the jsfiddle not working for you? It is working fine for me.

Comment: whats wrong with this code: https://jsfiddle.net/maciek303/rtk3h706/8/   ?

Comment: this is ok: https://jsfiddle.net/ilazycoder/9xuym2kj/1/ and this is not ok https://jsfiddle.net/maciek303/rtk3h706/8/  whats the difference ?